# Merge i18n properties file in maven overlay plugin

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have two web application projects in place, Project A and Project B. Project B has war dependency on Project A. Both projects have `messages.properties` files to handle i18n. However, the location of properties is same for both the projects. I am using maven war overlay plugin to overlay files of Project A on to Project B. If files are in the same location for these two projects, maven will not override Project B's files and leave them as is. However, this leads to maintenance problems as new text for i18n has to be added in messages.properties of both the web applications.

Is there a way to tell maven war overlay plugin to merge the properties files at the time of packaging? The logic of not overriding files when already present serves us well otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with the Maven Cargo plugin outputting an uberwar.

http://cargo.codehaus.org/Merging+WAR+files

It doesn't know how to merge properties files out of the box, but it's super easy to implement a custom merger, all you need to do is implement `org.codehaus.cargo.module.merge.MergeProcessor`, and have it available on the classpath.

You probably just want to write a simple merger that can concatenate files together, unless you have duplicate properties then you might need to do something a little more fancy.